# Gauge.js - color and gradients of gauge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to set the colors on a gauge from http://bernii.github.com/gauge.js/ however when I set

```
  colorStart: '#000000',   // Colors
  colorStop: '#ffffff',    // just experiment with them
```

These colors are fine, but instead of doing a gradient from left to right as a gauge should work, the gradient goes from bottom to top which makes no logical sense.

You can see an example on the right sidebar here.
http://app.calmpeople.co.uk/at/1512347430/1364379008

Comment: Have emailed the author, but not really sure what to do fromhere, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome, I see the whole gauge background colour change according to the value - i.e. the crescent background is green and changes to yellow then orange as the needle rises. There is no gradient. As far as I can see, this is correct behaviour.

Comment: Did you ever solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Besides `colorStart` and `colorStop` you also have to set property `gradientType: 1`

There is no mention of this option in documentation, only in the code:

```
gradientType: 0         # 0 : radial, 1 : linear
```